# How to place text between two columns and which breaks the rule dividing them in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, rules, columns, context-mkiv

I have two paragraphs of instructions and I need to indicate to readers that they have a choice of one or another. I am using this code, to put the data into different columns, with a line between:

```
\startcolumns[n=2, rule=on]
    \startlines
        This is some instructions.
    \stoplines
    \column
    \startlines
        This is some other instructions.
    \stoplines
\stopcolumns
```

This makes a document like this, with a nice divide line in the middle:

```
 _______________________________
|                               |
| This is some  : This is some  |
| instructions. : other instru- |
|               : ctions.       |
|                               |
|_______________________________|
```

I'd like to add the text "or", beween the two columns, to make it more clear that readers have a choice. This breaks the divide line and appears exactly in the middle, centered vertically on the line, and horizontally centered as well, e.g.:

```
 _______________________________
|                               |
| This is some  :  This is some |
| instructions. or other instr- |
|               :  uctions.     |
|                               |
|_______________________________|
```

How can I add "or" text to the line dividing the two columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't any inbuilt command do add text to the column rule. Assuming that you are only interested in two column text that **do not** break across pages, you can fake two column text using low-level TeX and add a frame using metapost.

```
\defineframed
  [fakecolumn]
  [location=top,
   width=0.45\textwidth,
   align=normal,
   frame=off]

\defineframed
    [ORcolumn]
    [location=top,
     height=\ORcolumnht,
     width=2.5em,
     frame=off,
     background=ORcolumn,
     top=\vss,
     bottom=\vss]

\defineoverlay[ORcolumn][\useMPgraphic{ORcolumn}]

\startuseMPgraphic{ORcolumn}
  ht := 2*StrutHeight;
  draw (OverlayWidth/2, OverlayHeight/2-ht/2) -- (OverlayWidth/2, 0);
  draw (OverlayWidth/2, OverlayHeight/2+ht/2) -- (OverlayWidth/2, OverlayHeight);

  setbounds currentpicture to boundingbox OverlayBox;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\newbox\leftcolumnbox   \newbox\rightcolumnbox
\newdimen\ORcolumnht

\def\startORcolumns#1\column#2\stopORcolumn
    {\blank
     \setbox\leftcolumnbox \hbox{\fakecolumn{#1}}%
     \setbox\rightcolumnbox\hbox{\fakecolumn{#2}}%
     % location=top sets the ht of the box to structheight
     % and depth to the remaining length
     \ORcolumnht=\dimexpr\strutheight+
         \dp\ifdim\dp\leftcolumnbox>\dp\rightcolumnbox\leftcolumnbox\else\rightcolumnbox \fi
    \hbox to \textwidth
      {\hss\copy\leftcolumnbox
       \hss\ORcolumn{OR}\hss
       \copy\rightcolumnbox\hss}%
      \blank}



\starttext
\input zapf
\startORcolumns
  \input knuth
  \column
  \input ward
\stopORcolumn
\input zapf
\stoptext
```

[image]