# Two-column layout with thick vertical rule in ConTeXt

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, context, two-column, rules

## Background

I would like to add a thick rule centered between two columns.

## Example Code

A minimum working example that illustrates the issue:

```
\setupcolors[state=start]

\startuseMPgraphic{StyleVerticalRule}
  thickness := 6.50pt;

  if CurrentColumn < NOfColumns :
    setbounds currentpicture to OverlayBox
      shifted( -3*thickness, 0 );

    draw rightboundary OverlayBox
      withpen pensquare scaled thickness
      withcolor \MPcolor{red};
  fi
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[StyleVerticalRule][
  \useMPgraphic{StyleVerticalRule},
]

\definecolumnset[StyleColumns][
  n=2,
  background=StyleVerticalRule,
]

% Horizontal line below the section header.
\define[2]\StyleSection{%
  \framed[
    frame=off,
    bottomframe=on,
    framecolor=pink,
    rulethickness=1.0pt,
    width=local,
  ]{\vbox{#2}}}


\setuphead[section][
  command=\StyleSection,
  after={\startcolumnset[StyleColumns]},
  aftersection={\stopcolumnset},
]

\starttext
\startbodymatter
  \startchapter[title={Chapter}, reference=sec:my-chapter,]
  \startsection[title={Section}, reference=sec:my-section,]
  \startsubsection[title={Equipment},reference=sec:my-equipment,]
    \input knuth
    \input knuth
  \stopsubsection
  \stopsection
  \stopchapter
\stopbodymatter

\stoptext
```

## Problem

The vertical rule height appears to be `\textheight`, rather than height of the columns. The code above produces:

[image: Over Extended Rule]

The vertical rule extends beyond the subsection header because, I think, it references `OverlayBox`. I would like to use the column height, not the text height, to produce:

[image: Perfectly Extended Rule]

## Questions

With respect to multi-column layouts:

- How do you restrict the height of the vertical rule so that it respects the column height (i.e., how do you determine the column height)?
- How would you add sufficient space to the section's column margins so that the vertical rule does not overlap any text?
- What is the required calculation to ensure the vertical rule is centered between the columns (i.e., `-3*thickness` seems... incorrect)?

I also could not find any definition for `OverlayBox`, although I found a few examples.

## Related

Information that is somewhat related:

- [How to place text between two columns and which breaks the rule dividing them in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59520/how-to-place-text-between-two-columns-and-which-breaks-the-rule-dividing-them-in)
- [formatting natural table header with conTeXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58320/formatting-natural-table-header-with-context)
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17813/2148
- [Creating a grid which fills available text area on a page in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57521/creating-a-grid-which-fills-available-text-area-on-a-page-in-context)
- http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2011/058352.html
- http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TABLE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using columnsets, your entire page design must be done using columnsets. So, if you want chapter or section heads to span the entire page, you will have to define a columnspan.

For simple two column documents, you can use `\startcolumns ... \stopcolumns`, or its MkIV replacement `\startmixedcolumns ... \stopmixedcolumns`. Here is an example:

```
\setupcolors[state=start]

\startuseMPgraphic{StyleVerticalRule}
  draw OverlayBox;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\defineoverlay[StyleVerticalRule][\useMPgraphic{StyleVerticalRule}]

\definemixedcolumns
  [sectioncolumns]
  [
    n=2, 
    separator=rule,
    rulecolor=red,
    rulethickness=6.5pt,
    balance=yes,
  ]

\setupalign[verytolerant,stretch,hanging]

% Horizontal line below the section header.
\defineframed[sectionframed]
             [
               frame=off,
               bottomframe=on,
               framecolor=pink,
               rulethickness=1.0pt,
               width=local,
               align=normal, % to get a vbox
             ]

\define[2]\StyleSection{\sectionframed{#2}}

\setuphead
    [section]
    [
      command=\StyleSection,
      after={\startsectioncolumns},
      aftersection={\stopsectioncolumns},
    ]

\starttext
\startchapter[title={Chapter}, reference=sec:my-chapter,]
  \startsection[title={Section}, reference=sec:my-section,]
      \startsubsection[title={Equipment},reference=sec:my-equipment,]
        \input knuth
        \input knuth
      \stopsubsection
  \stopsection
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Use `distance=<dim>` to change the distance between columns. BTW, "significantly" overflows the column width because TeX cannot find a good spot to hyphenate the word. You can get a slightly better hyphenation by using `align=tolerant`. To add space before the columns use `before={\blank[medium]}`.

Comment: Mixed columns do not accept a `align` key. You have to set the alignment using `\setupalign`.

Comment: Is there a key to specify the width of a *specific* column? (`\setupmixedcolumns[mycolumns][1][width=5em]` doesn't work.)