# ConTeXt: Stretch image width within a two-column layout

Tags: graphics, context, scaling, width

## Background

Trying to place an image [within two-column text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130421/two-column-layout-with-thick-vertical-rule-in-context).

## Problem

The image renders as follows, where the vertical bar is the column separator:

[image: Undefined Image]

## Code

The following code produces the problem image:

```
  \placefigure[]{}{%
    \externalfigure[7bee7b104cc5c6.jpg][
      width=\textwidth,
    ]
  }
```

The following code, however, successfully embeds the image:

```
  \placefigure[]{}{%
    \externalfigure[7bee7b104cc5c6.jpg][
      width=100px,
    ]
  }
```

The problem is that the width of `100px` does not cause the image to expand to the local width (i.e., the width of the current column).

## Ideas

Some things I have tried:

```
width=\textwidth,
width=\the\textwidth,
width=\linewidth,
width={\the\textwidth},
width=local,
```

And even [this](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/value:dimension):

```
\newdimen\imgwidth
\imgwidth=200px
...
width={\the\imgwidth},
```

## Question

How do you place a figure within a column such that it scales to fit the width?

## Minimum Working Example

Here is a small code snippet that illustrates the problem:

```
% interface=en output=pdftex

\definemixedcolumns[StyleColumns][
  n=2, 
  separator=rule,
  align=tolerant,
  before={\blank[big]},
]

\setupexternalfigures[
  order={svg,pdf,png,jpg},
  location=global,
  %wfactor=fit,
]

\setuphead[section][
  after={\startStyleColumns},
  aftersection={\stopStyleColumns},
]

\starttext

\startbodymatter
  \setuppagenumbering[conversion=numbers]
  \setcounter[userpage][1]

  \startchapter[
    title={Chapter},
    reference=sec:chapter,
  ]

  \startsection[
    title={Section},
    reference=sec:chapter,
  ]

  \placefigure[]{}{%
    \externalfigure[sheep.jpg][
        width=\textwidth,
      ]
  }

  \startsubsection[
    title={Equipment},
    reference=sec:equipment,]
    \input knuth
  \stopsubsection

  \stopsection
  \stopchapter
\stopbodymatter

\stoptext
```

Comment out the `width=\textwidth,` line to see the image appear.

Comment: Can you crate a minimal example to show that `width=\linewidth` or `width=\hsize` does not work.

Comment: @Aditya: `\hsize` works; `\linewidth` makes the image disappear altogether. Is `wfactor` less efficient than `width`?

Comment: Hmm...it seems that there is a bug with `\textwidth` and `\linewidth` inside mixed columns. Please report it to the context mailing list. Using `wfactor` is OK. I'd rather use `\defineexternalfigure[fullwidth][factor=fit]` and then use `\externalfigure[file.jpg][fullwidth]`, as it makes it easy to change the style if the style changes in the future. See [ConTeXt wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Using_Graphics#Settings_for_multiple_images) for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following:

```
\placefigure[]{}{%
  \externalfigure[7b104cc5c6.jpg][wfactor=fit]
}
```

The documentation for [`\externalfigure`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/externalfigure) refers to the [`\useexternalfigure`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/useexternalfigure) command. The **externalfigure** command appears to inherit all the behaviours of the **useexternalfigure** command, including `wfactor`. Use `wfactor` to control the stretch of the width, independently from the stretch of the height.

To ensure that all figures throughout the document use the same fit, you can define the fit requirement once:

```
\setupexternalfigures[
  order={svg,pdf,png,jpg},
  location=global,
  wfactor=fit,
]
```

The `location=global` indicates that the images can come from anywhere in the file system.